# How to get only a number of duplicates in Google sheet with Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I need help on Google Sheet regarding duplicates function.

I have data of Column A and B

- Column A contains URL
- Column B contains duplicate of the URL

I need the formula to sort the duplicates to have only for example 3 duplicates only.

So from this data:

[image]

To this data:

[image]

Using the google sheet function or formula.

All this time i try using manual and for big data resources would takes time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below is a solution that populates the three results for each unique url in column B as a row.

in cell C1:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,B:B<>""))
```

in cell D1:

```
=BYROW(C:C,LAMBDA(x,TRANSPOSE(FLATTEN(QUERY(A:B,"select * where B='"&x&"' limit 3",0)))))
```